# HTTP 500 Error in Symfony 3

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I created an app on my `localhost` using `symfony 3`. Stuff works perfectly well on my local host. Now my main problem is moving it to my shared hosting (`cPanel`). Moved the files to the `public_html` folder, then I moved the `.exe`, `bin`, `src`, `var`, etc folders to the parent folder (The folder containing the `public_html` folder) while leaving the 'web' folder in the `public_html`. I then moved everything from the 'web' folder (Which is inside the `public_html` folder) into the `public_html` folder. Making me have the following directory structure:

```
cpanel-root-directory<br>
---/app<br>
---/bin<br>
---/src<br>
---/tests<br>
---/var<br>
---/vendor<br>
---/public_html<br>
------/bundles<br>
------/css<br>
------/dist<br>
------/fonts<br>
------/img<br>
------/js<br>
------/plugins<br>
------/uploads<br>
------.htaccess<br>
------app.php<br>
------app_dev.php<br>
------apple-touch-icon.png<br>
------config.php<br>
------robots.txt<br>
<br>
```

When I go to the domain name, I keep getting this annoying `HTTP 500` error. Then on both `localhost` and on the server (at different times), I created a fresh new `symfony` project, dumped it in the server and got the "Welcome to Symfony 3" page quite alright. But, when I tried putting my controller files, and going to the routes defined in them (I use annotations in the `Sensio` bundle to define routes), I get that HTTP 500 error. Then, in the default controller that works, I try defining a new action 'testAction'. When I go to the route for the test action, I still get the `HTTP 500` error, but going to the '/' route, I see the `symfony` welcome page correctly.

My clients have seen that the stuff works perfectly well on my `localhost`, but now moving it to the server is the issue.

Comment: UPDATED!!! Please i checked doing www.mydomain,org/app_dev.php and it works perfectly but if i just go to the www.mydomain.org it gives me the HTTP 500 error.

Comment: I also had to comment out the checks in the app_dev.php file before i could get that to work.

/*if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}*/

Answer (score 1):

If you can (have access), just keep your web dir, and then make public_html a symlink to your web dir.

If you need to change the name of your "web" dir, you need to follow this instructions:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html

Comment: Did that.....got the same 500 error. Funny thing is that it works at www.mydomain.org/app_dev.php (Thats after i commented out that check in it) but i still get the HTTP 500 error when i go straight to www.mydomain.org

Comment: if when using /app_dev.php everything works, it's probably a cache error as Dan mentioned to you. Go ahead and delete var/cache/prod and try again.

Comment: Did that and its still the same thing
Is it safe to delete the var/cache + var/logs + var/sessions directories?

Comment: Yes, but I doubt that will fix your problem. Can you try to see the error logs in your hosting/cpanel to get a more descriptive message of the error?

Answer (score 1):

You should check this paragraph from [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory)

This part seems to describe exactly your problem:

> Some shared hosts have a public_html web directory root. Renaming your web directory from web to public_html is one way to make your Symfony project work on your shared host. Another way is to deploy your application to a directory outside of your web root, delete your public_html directory, and then replace it with a symbolic link to the web in your project.

Comment: Did that also but i still get the same result. Funny tho, it works at www.mydomain.org/app_dev.php (Thats after i commented out that check in it) but i still get the HTTP 500 error when i go straight to www.mydomain.org

Comment: Did you check your vhost target app.php and not index.php ? Did you check you are in prod environment and not developpement ? Did you try www.mydomain.org/app.php/yourRoute ?

Answer (score 0):

Eh, I think that's because, now, you are online, so you need to clear the cache for the prod environment:

```
$ php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

But you say you are on a shared hosting, so unless you have some available tools to access the terminal (and run the above command), then you need to manually delete the `var/cache/prod` directory if present.

Or if this doesn't work, I usually, don't upload the `var/cache` + `var/logs` + `var/sessions` directories at all, but create them manually as empty ones, and then let Symfony do its job with them by default.

## LE

Maybe you have another problem, and the one with the cache you've solve it already.
So, to check if there is something wrong with your app, enable the `dev` mode ( `app_dev.php` ), by modifying, locally, your `public_html/app_dev.php` file, and comment out these lines:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

And then, copy this file over the one on the server, and then access a route with `app_dev.php` in front, and see if there is an error (eg):

```
http://www.domain.com/app_dev.php/existing_route
```

After you are done, don't forget to uncomment the code inside `app_dev.php`,and re-upload the file on the server.

Comment: Deleted the directory as you said but it still throws the 500 error

Comment: Can i go ahead and delete the var/cache + var/logs + var/sessions directories?

Comment: @yommie No need to delete logs and sessions, I think. I usually delete only the `prod` directory inside `var/cache/`. And I never had probs.

Comment: @yommie But maybe you have another problem. To check it, see my LE.

Comment: Bites me that my routing works perfectly in app_dev.php uploaded it without the var/cache + var/logs + var/sessions directories and created them as empty directories instead. Still got that Error 500. Okay then i checked the logs and i found this
`[2017-02-24 14:36:51] request.INFO: Matched route "homepage". {"route":"homepage","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"homepage"},"request_uri":"http://veveedcash.org/","method":"GET"} []`
Honestly i have no such route defined in  my app (i deleted that default controller) @Strnm

Comment: @yommie Whenever you are modifying a script, in the prod env, you *do* need to remove the `var/cache/prod` content (at least that what's I'm doing, dunno if this is the right way to go). For example, even though you add an extra space, you need to clear the cache in order to see that new space.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to help me on this. I deleted the whole directory, allowed Symfony do its job and i still got the same thing. Here are the logs
Dev
`[2017-02-24 15:07:26] request.INFO: Matched route "home". {"route":"home","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\PublicController::homeAction","_route":"home"},"request_uri":"http://veveedcash.org/app_dev.php/","method":"GET"} []`

Comment: Then in the prod env i have `[2017-02-24 15:07:15] request.INFO: Matched route "homepage". {"route":"homepage","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"homepage"},"request_uri":"http://veveedcash.org/","method":"GET"} []`
I am not understanding why i would be getting different routes with the same request on different environments

Comment: Can you paste the error message from the logs/prod.log when you use the prod environment?
Also, you should edit your comments and remove your hostname